# Upgrade android 4.2.2 to 4.4?

Tags: updates

I have spice Mi 506 which runs on Android 4.2.2. Can I upgrade my phone to Android KitKat 4.4. If so how do I upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

There is no official update from Android 4.2.2 to Android 4.4 for the Spice Mi 506. However, you can use a custom ROM. Instructions for this can be found on [Update Spice MI 506 to Android 4.4 using custom ROM](http://www.kitkatrom.co/2015/07/spice-mi-506-stellar-mettle-icon-6322.html)

Use at your own risk, your Phone can be bricked afterwards and maybe you loose your warranty.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).